# How can I dynamically show the evolution of N variables in a plot?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have an `NxM` matrix `W` with floating point values in a function.

I want to be able to show in a figure the evolution over `X` iterations of each column.

The pseudo-code would be:

```
- open a window to show all values of column 1 of W..
- open a window to show all values of column 2 of W..
... 
- open a window to show all values of column M of W

    for iterations=1 to X
    <here some updates on values in W are made>
    {
     for i=1:M {
       for j=1:N {
           update value of W(i,j) in window j (without re-opening the window)
       }
    }

    }
```

I know the way to do this is something such as using the `plot` function but I don't understand it very well even after reading official documentation.

**EDIT 3 this is the code I have now**

```
  [~:X] = size(W);   
   for i=1:X
    plot(W(:,i));
    end
```

**It works. but how do I set "just print points"? and how to set the position of a figure (I mean,I wan figures don't appear one over the other?**

My **exact** objetive is the following:
Let's say W is a 10*3 matrix.

I want to have 3 FIGURES.

In each figure should be printed (and updated a certain number of times) the values of ALL values in the column i. The values should be printed AS POINTS (not like a function where each point is linked with others).

Each POINT represent an element W(i,j). More exactly the figure should be the rapresentation in a 2-D SPACE of a N-D SPACE where N = number of rows of W.

Any further suggestion?

Comment: instead of pseudo code, why don't you add what you've tried doing with `plot`?

Comment: I updated the thread with additional info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying this:

```
[~,X] = size(W);   
for i=1:X
    plot(W(:,i),[0:0.5:20],'none');
end
```

Which won't work because each column of `W` has 10 rows, and `[0:.5:20]` has 40 elements. You need to have vectors of matching lengths for this to work, which you don't.

From your description, I think you might be looking for [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html), which has multiple sets of contained within a single "figure window":

```
figure;
[R,C] = size(W); 
for i=1:C
    subplot(C,1,i); #% creates axes for each column
    plot(W(:,i),1:R,'.k'); #% has appropriate x values
                #%   ^---- '.k' indicates unconnected dots (.), colored black (k)
end
```

From the comments below, the question-asker is looking for a way to create figure windows so that each one contains a maximum of 4 subplots.  There are many ways to do this; I've included one option below.

```
num_subplots = 4;
[R,C] = size(W); 
for i=1:C
    this_subplot_position = mod(i,num_subplots) + 1;
    if this_subplot_position == 1
        figure;
    end
    subplot(num_subplots,1,this_subplot_position); #% creates axes for each column
    plot(W(:,i),1:R,'.k'); #% has appropriate x values
                #%   ^---- '.k' indicates unconnected dots (.), colored black (k)
end
```

Comment: With second solution it says "Error in color/linetype argument" while with first "Vectors must be the same lengths."

Comment: I hadn't looked closely enough at your linespec string.  I've edited my answer with a linespec that will produce black unconnected points.

Comment: ok it works! just one problem left. How I get the figure to "fullscreen" and how do I manage to update the SAME figure? (it create a enew figure at each iteration)

Comment: (I got to update the same figure,just left "how to have a fullscreen window")

Comment: Try this link on [how to make fullscreen figure windows](http://infinitesimalmind.blogspot.com/2008/06/full-screen-figures-in-matlab.html).  (Google is your friend.)

Comment: yes,it works! thank you very much. I just ask you last tip: If I have many inputs I would needed a 100 inch screen. How should I tell matlab "each 4 inputs make a new figure"? (and also how to display "column number" in each subplot?)

Comment: Edited with one example of how to do a new figure each 4 subplots. There are as many ways to do this as you can imagine though; this is the kind of thing you really should be figuring out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

By window, I hope you mean figure. Could you clarify that? You have a 2 dimensional array and you want to plot that column by column in seperate figures?

```
figure(i);
plot(W(:,i),[0:0.5:20],linespecs); %to plot ith column on y axis, and x axis as ur [0:0.5:20]
```

For updating, just change the value, and it should change the figure accordingly.

Comment: yes. with a window I mean a "floating figure ". But I don't understand "%to plot ith column on y axis, and x axis as ur [0:0.5:20]". Could you explain me this?

Comment: W(:,i) is your i-th column in the matrix W, so that goes on ur Y axis, [0:0.5:20] creates a matrix from 0 to 20 with spacing as 0.5 to be used as ur X axis. If u want to plot the columns vs row, u can change the second parameter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab includes a command called `refreshdata` that makes problems like this a bit easier. In the example below we plot every column of `W` only once, but we set the `YDataSource` property so the plots automatically update when we later call `refreshdata`. The `YDataSource` property is a string containing a valid variable or command; here, it's `W(:, 1)` for the first plot, `W(:, 2)` for the second plot, etc.

```
for i_plot = 1:M
    subplot(M, 1, i_plot);
    plot(W(:, i_plot), '.', 'YDataSource', ['W(:, ' num2str(i_plot) ')']);
end

for i_plot = 1:M
    for i_point = 1:N
        W(i_point, i_plot) = rand;
        refreshdata;
        pause(0.1);
    end
end
```